# Can I disable my Companion in Skyforge?

Tags: skyforge

I need to catch healing hands in Okki Island but my companion keeps killing the boss before I can even do anything at all.

Is there a way I can stop him from attacking or disable him?

I can't complete the quest for the bastion.